# Why is go http streaming server not sending lines successfully?

Tags: go

I have a very basic http server and http client. The server is not sending out the data when chunked despite flushing it. I have validated both with a go http client and curl.

Here is the server:

```
func main() { 
    r := mux.NewRouter()
    baseURL := ""
    r.HandleFunc(baseURL+"/",handler).Methods("GET")
    listener, _ := net.Listen("tcp", "127.0.0.1:0")
    http.Handle("/",r)
    go http.Serve(listener,nil)
    url = "http://" + listener.Addr().String() + "/"
    fmt.Println(url)
    TestSend()
}

func writeHeaders(w http.ResponseWriter, code int) {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/plain")
    w.WriteHeader(code)
}

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Println("handler")
    writeHeaders(w, 200)
    rsc := bufio.NewScanner(strings.NewReader(response))
    for rsc.Scan() {
        sender <- rsc.Text()
    }
    for d := range sender {
        w.Write([]byte(d))
        w.(http.Flusher).Flush()
        fmt.Println("wrote and flushed "+d)
    }
}
```

And the client:

```
res, _ := http.Get(url)
reader := bufio.NewReader(res.Body)
for {
    fmt.Println("ReadBytes")
    data, err := reader.ReadBytes('\r')
    fmt.Println("read")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error!")
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println("read line "+string(data))
}
```

I get the server saying it is sending and flushing, and I get the "ReadBytes" saying it is waiting to read, but it never reads any lines:

```
$ go run httptest.go
http://127.0.0.1:55967/
handler
wrote and flushed abc
wrote and flushed def
wrote and flushed ghi
wrote and flushed jkl
wrote and flushed mno
ReadBytes
(here it just waits)
```

If, while it is running, I curl, I get the right headers, but no data:

```
$ curl -i http://127.0.0.1:55957/
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/plain
Date: Sun, 02 Aug 2015 07:01:21 GMT
Transfer-Encoding: chunked


(no data here at all)
```

Clearly the data is not leaving the server, but why? I am `Flush`ing it.

Comment: Are you sure the response you're sending includes `\r`?

Comment: Hmm, I think it is, but that would be a real "Doh!" moment, wouldn't it? :-) Checking now...

Comment: Well, I wasn't... but it isn't making much of a difference. I tried CR, LF, CRLF, LFCR, no combination makes any difference. Either way, that would mess up the go client reader, but not the curl, which just shows data.

Comment: you're not showing how `sender` and `response` work, but one suspicious thing is that you're not writing to the channel and reading from it concurrently. can you try removing that whole part and just send some static lines to the writer and flush? it should work...

Comment: Yeah, I know it is weird. I am isolating the issue from a more complex app. Either way, it just didn't work. But I will retry now.

Comment: Nah, same thing. Nothing being read on the client - whether go or curl - correct chunked headers, though. Tearing my hair out.

Comment: Let me write an example that does work and you can compare

Comment: here's a server that works perfectly in curl. the actual writing code is yours, just the way we produce messages is different. http://play.golang.org/p/mRfU7tXPE6

Comment: Thanks, trying that now. If it works on my laptop, then the problem is my code; else it is something on the laptop

Comment: Yours works, mind doesn't, still trying to understand why, though

Comment: It has to do with the `bufio.Scanner` combined with the \r\n. Still not sure what...